# Handling pgPL/SQL exceptions From QtSQL

Tags: sql, qt, postgresql

**Short and simple:**

How to catch pgPL/SQL exceptions with QtSQL?

I haven't found any example or info at the docs.

**More details:**

I'm developing the front end for a system with Qt 5.3. The database perform some validation at some of the inputs and raise custom exceptions when something is invalid. What I want is to be able to handle these exceptions at he front end code, showing appropriate messages to the user.

**EDIT:**

I have tried to use the `QSqlError` class. Although it gave me the exception, it gave me too much data which will need to be parsed to be useful. Is there a way to get the exception raised without parsing the messages?

Comment: Have you used `QSqlError::databaseText()` and `QSqlError::driverText ()` separately?

Comment: You should be able to get the `SQLSTATE` at least. **Never** parse error message text. Use the `SQLSTATE` and any driver-specific fields available. (You can `RAISE` exceptions from PL/PgSQL with specific `SQLSTATE`s). If Qt doesn't offer access to this then its database error handling is *horribly* broken.

Comment: Did a little more looking, and it seems that the Qt team forgot to copy Java this time. JDBC throws useful exceptions with SQLState etc. The Qt exceptions look pretty seriously useless for real work, they don't give you a locale-and-version independent way to say anything except "Um, it didn't work". Here's how it *should* look: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html . (IMO this is a Qt defect, probably an outright API bug).

Comment: I've reported a bug against Qt for this. See https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-40586#comment-251940 . Vote for it if you think it's appropriate, and watch the bug so you're notified if anything changes. In the mean time you'll have to run a patched Qt, or just use the buggy and unsafe method of poking around in the error message text in the hope of identifying the error.

Comment: I managed to find out after asking the question here. The method `QSqlError::nativeErrorCode` that will give the SQLSTATE. But the people who developed the database stored procedures and triggers decided to use this property running far far away from the specification. The problem was not Qt or PostgreSQL.